# How do I find the address returned by container_of?

Tags: c, struct

I'm not looking to implement the function, but I am wondering how to conceptually think about it. For example, a struct contains 5 integers. The size of each integer, from sizeof () is 4. If the address of the 5th element is 0x8b1000d how do I find the address of the struct? I've read that the address of the struct is the address of the 1st element. So do I just subtract the size of each integer from the address of the 5th in order to find that?

Comment: The C standard allows any amount of padding between fields, so the answer to your question is no.  You can use the `offsetof` macro http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/offsetof.3.html to find the number of bytes from the start of the struct to any of its fields. With this you can find the start of the struct given the address of one of its fields after casting it to `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use the offsetof macro (`#include <stddef.h>`) to get the byte offset of the field in question and subtract that from the address of the field to get the address of the beginning of the struct.

Given the address of a field in a structure, all you have to do is subtract the offset of that field (produced by `offsetof`) from the address of the field and that gives you the address of the structure. There's some casting involved, but that's basically it. Here's an example:

```
struct blah {
    int a, b, c, d, e;
} xyz;

int *my_blah_e = &xyz.e;
struct blah *my_blah = (struct blah *) (((char *) my_blah_e) - offsetof(blah, e));
// my_blah == &xyz
```

Comment: So it'd be correct to add the byte offset to the integer size and then subtract that amount until I reach the begging address of element 1?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helps